# Populating a task stream with a revision different than head

Tags: perforce

I am trying to populate a task stream with an older revision than #head.

So I created a task stream, and did not chose to automatically branch any files.

Then I try :

```
>p4 populate -r -S //depot/dev //depot/main/...@some_label_vXXXX
Label 'some_label_vXXXX' is restricted to use on server 'Edge', not on server 'MASTER'.
```

I am connected to the edge server so I am not quite sure what is the issue there. If I need to have a global label to be able to branch, is there a way to convert an existing local to global label ?

Anyway, I try using a changelist instead.

```
>p4 populate -r -S //depot/dev //depot/main/...@1456175
//depot/main/...@1456175 - no target file(s) in branch view.
```

What happens there ? Is this an issue with the FromFile ? And what would be the proper way to populate a task stream using an existing label/changelist ?

Playing with P4V, it seems the command executed is (and this works) :

```
>p4 populate -o //depot/main/...@1456175 //depot/dev/...
```

I am still interested in understanding why the '-rS' does not work.

Comment: The label you created is local to your Edge Server, but the populate command runs directly on the Commit Server. I believe you can use 'unload' and 'reload' to turn your local label into a global label. We might have to understand more about the stream definition of stream //depot/dev to understand why the populate -r -S didn't think that stream's parent was //depot/main.

Comment: //depot/main is a development branch and //depot/dev is the child task stream. I am not sure of the syntax because according to the documentation the 'populate -S' command does not take a fromFile argument. So from my understanding it seems if I want a specific revision I should not use -S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this syntax:

```
p4 populate -r -S //depot/dev //depot/main/...@1456175
```

//depot/main/... is limiting the toFile, which is not what you want.  This should work:

```
p4 populate -r -S //depot/dev @1456175
```

Giving the stream name already generates the fromFile->toFile view, so there's no need to specify either of them a second time.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `-r` and swap the source and destination arguments?

Comment: There are no "source and destination arguments" in this form of the command, which is what confused OP.  :)  `-S //depot/dev` generates the view (both halves), and `-r` flips it.  There is no spot for a `fromFile` argument here.  See `p4 help populate`.  You *can* run a command like `p4 populate //depot/main/...@1456175 //depot/dev/...` (which is the `fromFile toFile` form) but that's different from `p4 populate -S //depot/dev`.